# The best way to send (and recive) a string via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: php, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

Following some other posts it can be done via

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X","Y");
xmlhttp.send("name=MyName&mode=delete");
```

My Questions:

- What are X and Y? Why do i need them and how do i use them?
- How do i read the properties "name" and "mode" in my test.php file?

This may be very basic questions, but im new to this stuff and cant find a basic answer on the internet so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setRequestHeader(header,value)
```

Adds HTTP headers to the request.

`header`: specifies the header name

`value`: specifies the header value

Commonly used to specify the data type you want to send in the send() method.

**Example:** data as an html form

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

---

In php:

`$_POST['name']` to retrieve name value
`$_POST['mode']` to retrieve mode value